# Ruby Foreign Key Constraints in Database vs Model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, foreign-keys

I have the following models in a Rails app. This setup has worked fine since normally when I would like to add a new VendorPromo to a vendor, there's a dropdown in the view of available Promos to choose from. Now, I'm enabling the creation of new VendorPromos via an API. However, this current set up will allow the creation of a VendorPromo with any promo_id, even if it doesn't exist in Promo. I've seen the `belongs_to :promo, foreign_key: :promo`, and I know you can add a foreign key constraint via the DB as well. What I'd like to know is the difference between these two approaches and if one is better?

Edit: I recognize that application constraints are different than DB constraints, but when I apply the constraint in the app, i.e. the `belongs_to :promo, foreign_key: :promo` it doesn't actually seem to enforce the constraint at all. Specifically, I can create a new VendorPromo with a promo_id of, say, 13, even though Promo only has IDs between 1 and 8.

```
class Vendor
  has_many :vendor_promos
end

class VendorPromo
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :promo
end

class Promo
end
```

Comment: Foreign key constraints help us maintain valid data and are yet another way of helping us to avoid unexpected nil values in our applications. It’s unrealistic to expect application logic alone to provide the same level of protection.

Comment: I think with the id out of range, unless you have presence validations on other attributes, then it's creating that record. You could put null contraints in the db and in the model to ensure that the model cannot be created without other attributes being there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juan Carlos's answer was part of the way there. It's true that the `foreign_key` attribute in `belongs_to` does not enforce any database or application level foreign key. What I was looking for was the `belongs_to :promo, optional: false` flag does in fact enforces an application level foreign key. That flag, in addition to a DB level foreign key constraint resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreign_key` attribute in the `belongs_to` method is not actually defining a foreign key, it's specifying for rails's internals which field holds the foreign  key.

The Ruby on Rails Guide warns you about it here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-foreign-key

> In any case, Rails will not create foreign key columns for you. You need to explicitly define them as part of your migrations.